# My WPdiscuz shortcode appears at the top of the page

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am using this code to generate a shortocode for my WPdiscuz plugin:

```
function my_wpdiscuz_shortcode() {
    if(file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/templates/comment/comment-form.php')){
        include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/templates/comment/comment-form.php';
    }
}


add_shortcode( 'wpdiscuz_comments', 'my_wpdiscuz_shortcode' );
```

However, when adding the shortcode `[wpdiscuz_comments]` it get the content always displayed at the top of the page.

How can I make the shortcode display the content within I add the shortcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw on the Beaver Builder Facebook group you having some issues with it showing as duplicate still so thought I'd share the code I use for WP Shortcodes that need another PHP script including.

It's similar to the previous answer but I thought it's worth a try if you're still having the issue.

```
function my_wpdiscuz_shortcode() {
    $html = "";
    if(file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/templates/comment/comment-form.php')){
        ob_start();
        include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/templates/comment/comment-form.php';
        $html = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'wpdiscuz_comments', 'my_wpdiscuz_shortcode' );
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcodes always need to return output.

```
function my_wpdiscuz_shortcode() {
    if(file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/templates/comment/comment-form.php')){
        ob_start();
        include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/templates/comment/comment-form.php';
        return ob_get_contents();
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'wpdiscuz_comments', 'my_wpdiscuz_shortcode' );
```

Comment: The code works, but now the comments are appearing at the top and bottom. Its a duplicate.